# Is it possible to store a method return value in the database without having a corresponding attribute?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have the following class.

```
@Entity
public class ShiftDetail {
  @Id
  private Integer id = null;
  private String name = null;

  private LocalTime startTime = null;
  private LocalTime endTime = null;

  public Duration getShifDurationInSeconds() {
    return Duration.between(this.startTime, this.endTime).toSeconds();
  }
}
```

For making some down-the-line processing easier, I would like to store the derived value "ShiftDurationInSeconds" in the database.

Is there a way to do this with JPA/ Hibernate without creating an attribute in the class?

Comment: Please don't initialise class members as `null`, they are set to `null` by default.

Comment: @maksimov, anything that speaks against it other than that it does the assignment twice?

Comment: This is code. It is supposed to have meaning. Every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@PreUpdate` and `@PrePersist` for calculate field persist in database.

```
private long shiftDurationInSeconds;

@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
public void calShiftDurationInSeconds() {
    shiftDurationInSeconds = Duration.between(this.startTime, this.endTime).getSeconds();
}
```